# Why microphone doesn't work on Ubuntu only?

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I've partitioned my Hardware into 2 OS a long time ago, the default one is Windows, the second one is Ubuntu, I don't think this info will be useful, but just to say that on Windows everything works fine but now that I need to work on Ubuntu the microphone is just dead. I've tried to install pavucontrol handling and regulating the input sound devices in multiple ways, but the input level just doesn't grow, as if input volume weren't on-setted. Moreover I've tried to add a line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf without success and I've tried to fixed this problem using alsamixer to. Can someone help me please? I really need to fix this problem, any illustrated example will be more appreciated.
Here's some info:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 133
    Memory at a4428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a4410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```